# Use webcam with opencv without x

Tags: opencv, webcam, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I want to use opencv with a webcam on a headless system, no ui/x, on a raspberry pi (Raspbian)

Is this feasible? Has it been done?

Comment: Using vnc it works albeit a bit slow, if i run it through ssh it doesn't find the webcam (Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display:)

Comment: I must check that i am not calling any gui

Comment: It does work just need to improve the speed

Comment: hi, did you find any solution? I am trying to do the same!

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is no X strictly needed to get and process images/video in opencv taken from webcam/raspicam.
You need to acquire the img raw data stream from cam matrix interface and then do what you whant in SDL/OGL etc

See
    [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38801999/using-imshow-in-opencv-without-running-x) and
    [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24872281/opencv-display-image-without-x-server) and
    [here faq](http://answers.opencv.org/question/57565/can-i-use-opencv-without-gui/)