# opencv display image without x server

Tags: image, opencv, raspberry-pi, command-line-interface

I need to display an image in Linux from startup without starting an x server

Using opencv

I am using rasbian on Raspberrypi

The error is cannot start GTK code (from cli)
Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display:

basic code could be

```
#include <cv.h>
#include <cvaux.h>
#include <highgui.h>
using namespace cv;
int main(int argc, char* argv[ ]){
 Mat image = imread(argv[1]);
 namedWindow(“Sample Window”);
 imshow(“Sample Window”,image);
 waitKey(0);
 return 0;
}
```

Any further questions or answers welcome!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the SDL library

[Home page SDL](https://www.libsdl.org/)