# Using imshow in opencv without running X

Tags: opencv, raspberry-pi, debian, x11, imshow

I've got an application with a Raspberry Pi running Debian that is pretty performance demanding and I am trying to avoid starting X when booting and jumping directly into the program.  This works fine, but if I would like to use the 'imshow' function in OpenCV, it does not work correctly, instead it says 'GTK-Warning: cannot open display" and exits the program.

Is it feasible to display a fullscreen image/video capture with opencv using imshow or any other function without X, or is it entirely dependent on the X?

Thanks,

---

For clarification, there is a monitor, it just shows the terminal prompt instead of a desktop.  So the raspberry pi is getting an image to a screen at the correct resolution, I guess what I don't understand is what X11 does for opencv as far as handling of the window/image?  I imagine a lot that cant be easily replicated.

But maybe a lightweight X11 alternative would be the best way to go if there's not another option, thanks for the tip.

Comment: You may be able to use a lightweight X server like Xfce, or maybe stream the frames from OpenCV to some other machine via RTSP or similar for viewing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, obviously the video output has to go somewhere... You could try Xvfb as a lightweight alternative to a full X11 instance.

Comment: ... but you won't be able to see it, because it is virtual, surely?

Comment: Indeed, it's only in memory. Ah... now I understand. Hmm, there are some players that use SDL, that uses its own video drivers. But I don't think those support OpenCV.

Comment: I think you're right, just a lightweight alternative would probably simplify things.

Comment: ok I might be too late asking here, but I wonder how does **raspistill -v** works and displays camera output without using gtk or X11, can we use the same approach to make opencv display images/videos?